# React Native <Button /> onPress not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[Here's a video of the button not clicking in action](https://gfycat.com/deliriousreasonablebarracuda).

I'm following the [React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react) and have a very simple setup:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";

const Styles = {
  image: { width: 200, height: 200 },
};

const Cat = () => {
  const [isHungry, setIsHungry] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: "https://reactnative.dev/docs/assets/p_cat2.png",
        }}
        style={Styles.image}
      />
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("Pressed!");
          setIsHungry(false);
        }}
        disabled={!isHungry}
        title={isHungry ? "Milk please!" : "Thanks!"}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Cat />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is running on my android phone (OnePlus 6), using Expo.

When I press the button, I get the click interaction, but the onPress function isn't called.

Even if I wipe out everything and just use the code directly on the docs' page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

const Cat = (props) => {
  const [isHungry, setIsHungry] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        I am {props.name}, and I am {isHungry ? "hungry" : "full"}!
      </Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          setIsHungry(false);
        }}
        disabled={!isHungry}
        title={isHungry ? "Pour me some milk, please!" : "Thank you!"}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Cafe = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Cat name="Munkustrap" />
      <Cat name="Spot" />
    </>
  );
}

export default Cafe;
```

What's going on here? For reference:

- Am on the latest React Native / Expo versions
- RNDebugger is open and is my primary, focussed tab
- I've refreshed / reloaded the app several times to no avail
- After pressing it 20ish times, I can finally get onPress to fire

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?! Seems very basic but it's extremely frustrating.

Comment: nothing seems out of the ordinary. try turning off debugger & restarting bundler

Comment: Turns out it was some sort of Expo issue; restarting the debugger and my phone fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

hmm thats strange, I ran your code on codesandbox and everything seems to work fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-taussig-c54q1?file=/src/App.js

onPress triggers on the first press.

I even opened the sandbox on my phone browser and it worked as intended. Try restarting your phone and creating a fresh project with code copied from the docs.

I wanted to comment this but since this is a new account, commenting is unavailable for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check out here. There is not problem I guess. https://snack.expo.io/@jasurkurbanov/2be06d